Create an LSTM Model based on multiple arrays events of random numbers
I need help on create a LSTM Model based on a complex structure of data.
I have a multidimensional array. It is an array of over 4000 arrays, each one consists of six numbers (from 1 to 128).
I have found a partial predction feature.
Suppose I select a group of 70 arrays [0..69], and I want to predict the 71th sequence. It is quitely impossible. But, if I could know the numbers on 71th sequence, I exclude all sequences from 0 to 69 that has inside at least one of the numbers in 71th sequence.
Then, I take all numbers on the remaining sequences once time (without duplicating), and I out them into an array naned Exclusion.
If I exclude all numbers on Exclusion from 1 to 128, I got a reducted group of numbers (from 9 to 14 elements). In this last reduced array I have surely the numbers on 71th sequence.
Now this model is replicable for all sequences: [1..70] for 72th, [2..71] for 73th,  and so on, for all sequences.
So, I cannot understand how to create a LSTM Model where I need to input a [70, 6] with an output of [70, 1], where [70, 6] is the 70 sequences of 6 numbers, and [70, 2] is the 70 vales between 1 and 0,  where 1 is the represented sequence to exclude.
I need globally to predict which sequences could be excluded.

I think an illustration might be good with smaller dimension. Plus typo, it's [70, 1] not [70, 2]? For general training of the LSTM, I would say make a dataset where you have your x and y, then find a good loss for your LSTM. In your case this is a binary classification task, if I understand well, so a sigmoid+negative log does the job.

First 70 Sequences [0 ... 69]:

[
    [ 5, 43, 7, 128, 124, 9 ],
    [ 124, 60, 24, 59, 26, 52 ],
    [ 8, 59, 46, 1, 99, 65 ],
    [ 3, 86, 64, 77, 119, 12 ],
    [ ... ],
    [ 112, 99, 104, 70, 108, 58 ]
]
(This is the initial data with shape [70, 6])


The Event to predict (71th Sequence):
[ 18, 128, 108, 100, 86, 94 ]


Sequence to be discard: 
[ 0, 1, 1, 0, ... , 1, 0 ]
(This the output of model, with shape [70, 1])


Numbers to discard from 1 to 128:
[ 124, 60, 24, 59, 26, 52, 8, 46, 1, 99, 65, ... ]
(Note: "59" is taken only once because is present on sequences 1 and 2)


Reduced numbers from 1 to 128:
[ 16, 18, 73, 45, 128, 108 , 98, 51, 86, 73, 66, 94, 12 ]
(In this reduced group of numbers, there are the numbers inside the 71th Sequence)

This is the representation of a single sequence. I wish it could be more explained.
